# Jenkins don't see command virtualenv

Tags: python, jenkins

I trying configure new jekins server and jobs. I have Jenkins ver. 2.19.4. I have some issue with virtualenv and I don't know what to do

my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
pip install virtualenv

PYENV_HOME=$WORKSPACE/.pyenv/

# Delete previously built virtualenv
if [ -d $PYENV_HOME ]; then
    rm -rf $PYENV_HOME
fi

# Create virtualenv and install necessary packages
virtualenv --no-site-packages $PYENV_HOME
. $PYENV_HOME/bin/activate

pip install paramiko
python ./deploy.py USER@IP
```

this should deploy my builded UI to server, but I need installed `paramiko` lib but jekins don't see a virutalenv and also have problem with installing paramiko itself

output log:

```
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
/tmp/hudson5253487294321466077.sh: line 12: virtualenv: command not found
/tmp/hudson5253487294321466077.sh: line 13: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UI3/.pyenv//bin/activate: No such file or directory
Collecting paramiko
  Using cached paramiko-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko)
.
.
.
failed on install crypthography
.
.
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zukA89/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pprj1d-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zukA89/cryptography/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./deploy.py", line 7, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is do not do this installation in Jenkin's task. Prepare the runtime environment in your build farm machine first. Then write the Jenkins task script to do the rest of the work.

BTW, virtualenv does't work very well with Jenkins because it create a new environment and may have some problems to inherite env variable that Jenkins needed.